# How to set Cesium JS map center (coordinates: latitude & longitude)

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I would like to initialize [cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) so that the map is centered on some specific coordinates instead of the default ones. I have the following initialization code:

```
var map = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('map-js');
map.centralBody.terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url : 'http://cesiumjs.org/smallterrain'
});
```

Usually, with other mapping libraries, I would set the center on initialization, eg on mapbox:

```
map = L.mapbox.map('map-js', 'api-key').setView([42.12, 12.45], 9);
```

How to do that with **cesium**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this after your first block of code above:

```
var scene = map.scene;
var ellipsoid = Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84;
var west = Cesium.Math.toRadians(-77.0);
var south = Cesium.Math.toRadians(38.0);
var east = Cesium.Math.toRadians(-72.0);
var north = Cesium.Math.toRadians(42.0);

var extent = new Cesium.Rectangle(west, south, east, north);
scene.camera.viewRectangle(extent, ellipsoid);
```

More examples are available in our [Camera Demo](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Camera.html&label=Showcases).

*EDIT (May 2014): Due to Cesium API changes, `.getCamera()` is renamed `.camera`, the camera's `.controller` was removed and rolled into the camera itself, and `Extent` is renamed to `Rectangle`.  The above code now reflects the new API.  For a complete list of breaking changes, see [CHANGES.md](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/CHANGES.md).*

Comment: how can I convert a lat/long coordinate into an extent? I'm puzzled

Comment: If you have a single lat/lon pair, instead of 4 corners, just create the corners by adding or subtracting an offset from your point.  The larger the offset, the more "zoomed out" the camera will be.

Comment: what about:

flight = Cesium.CameraFlightPath.createAnimationCartographic(map.scene, {
    destination : Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(coords.lng, coords.lat, coords.zoom),
    duration: 0
   });

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep the current "zoom" (aka camera distance from ellipsoid) and only have lon/lat, you could call [setView()](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html) and use the current camera height, like:

```
    viewer.camera.setView({
        destination : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
            longitude,
            latitude,
            Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84.cartesianToCartographic(viewer.camera.position).height
        )
    });
```