# Cesium JS : center map in 2d scene mode

Tags: javascript, dictionary, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium JS and I am a beginner. I initialised Cesium in 2D scene mode and I can't center the map.

Here is what I tried:

```
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer', {
    sceneMode : Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D
});
// try to center somewhere in Europe
widget.scene.camera.setPositionCartographic(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(10, 45, 500000));
```

I also tried with `scene.camera.viewRectangle(rectangle, ellipsoid);` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650127/how-to-set-cesium-js-map-center-coordinates-latitude-longitude). I tried the flight too.

All methods above work great in 3D scene mode but not in 2D. So I tried to put my camera where I want in 3D and switch to 2D mode with `SceneModePickerViewModel.morphTo2D()`. Still not working...

I know I am missing the whole point about center the map in 2D scene mode. Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flyTo method worked for me. I'm using Cesium 1.37.

```
viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(0.0, 0.0, 40000000),
    duration: 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A centering - in a sense of changing the origin - of a map is not supported in 2D mode, if you have zoomed completely out. you can take a look at the forums : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cesium-dev/centering/cesium-dev/rj2pDY1Hie8/hH2xJhIzCC0J

Try `SCENE3D`, and `COLUMBUS_VIEW`, with `viewRectangle` - works for me. If you are in Columbus view, do not forget to add a `camera.setPositionCartographic ( Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(a,b,c));`, where a,b,c, are usually -90, 45, and a small number of your choice, e.g. 2 to orient the direction of the map.